# Getting NURBS in and out of Blender

Tags: export, bezier-curves, import

Is there a working way to get NURBS curves into and out of Blender?

FBX supports this, but when I import an FBX with NURBS, the curve is not created.  I've tried with several versions.  FBXes exported with blender do not contain correct curve data.

OBJ export appears to work, but when I re-import them, the curve paramaterisation does not match what was exported.

IGES support doesn't appear to be available in the list of plugins, either.

Comment: I tried with OBJ. I managed to export a curve as NURBS (although knots seem way off), but surfaces are just transformed into meshes before exporting. Import adds just a bunch of vertices without any surface. Tried both legacy and new Wavefront importer/exporter with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For export, this is the best I found: https://www.digital-sculptors.com/cms/index.php/software/blender-plugins/63-export-iges.html

SubD will be exported as patches in an IGES file that can be made into a solid if the subdivision surface mesh was manifold.

For import I do not know a good way, please upvote this features request and comment on it: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/v8g8/